# Converting speeds in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had written a code beforehand, but was only just made aware by my teacher that the speed is supposed to be mph, rather than mps. I made necessary changes but I keep on receiving an error. The context of the code isn't important.

```
import re

# DATA
distance = 0.06 # Distance between the Camera A and B; 0.06 = 600 metres
speed_limit = 20 # (meters per second)

number_plates = ["DV61 GGB",      #UK
                 "D31 EG 2A",     #F
                 "5314 10A02",    #F
                 "24TEG 5063",    #F
                 "TR09 TRE",      #UK
                 "524 WAL 75",    #F
                 "TR44 VCZ",      #UK
                 "FR52 SWD",      #UK
                 "100 GBS 12",    #F
                 "HG55 BPO"       #UK
                 ]

enter = [7.12,7.17,7.22,7.12,7.23,7.41,7.18,7.25,7.11,7.38]
leave = [7.56,7.39,7.49,7.56,7.45,7.57,7.22,7.31,7.59,7.47]

mph=2.236936

# Find the non-UK plates
pattern = "(?![A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}$)"
foreign_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: re.match(pattern, x), number_plates))

# Calculations for speed
elapsed = [(l - e)/100 for l, e in zip(leave, enter)]
speed_mps = [distance/t for t in elapsed]

def mps_to_mph():
    speed = [s*h for s,h in zip(speed_mps,mph)]

mps_to_mph()
print(speed)
```

The error:

```html
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\ICT Coursework\Task 2.1.py", line 35, in <module>
    mps_to_mph()
  File "M:\ICT Coursework\Task 2.1.py", line 33, in mps_to_mph
    speed = [s*h for s,h in zip(speed_mps,mph)]
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

Perhaps, is `speed = [s*h for s,h in zip(speed_mps,mph)]` not the right way to convert the speed?

Comment: What is `zip`? I doubt it's the compression format.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: Search for `DV61 GGB` on StackOverflow, this is a recurring homework question and many solutions have been posted

Comment: All of them were asked by me, lol.

Comment: why not just `speed = [s*mph for s in speed_mps]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) is for iterating through two (or more) sequences in parallel. You are passing it one sequence and one number. I think you mean this:

```
speed = [s*mph for s in speed_mps]
```